# DbContext CommandTimeout too long, are there any risks?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I currently work for a project where they have modified the DbContext CommandTimeout to 1800 seconds (30 minutes). I have read that the default value is 30 seconds. It feels like a bad practice and I have no good arguments why it might cause problems

The code looks like this:

```
public WmoEntities(): base("name=WmoEntities")
{
    this.Database.CommandTimeout = 1800;
}
```

I wonder what the risks are if you make the CommandTimeout too long.

Comment: Well, you have users that like to wait 30 minutes for a response? If so, everything is fine. Otherwise you should improve your queries. Consider that in ASP.NET it's possible that the client already closed the browser or reloaded the page and the server still tries 30 minutes to process a previous request where the user is already gone long time ago. So you are wasting a lot of server resources for nothing. Now consider that 1000 users call this page at the same time. Time to improve the query and probably the database if it takes so long time.

Comment: Setting `CommandTimeout` to larger value just preventing timeout exception when request exceeds undesired time limit. It doesn't deal significant problem to data usage, but in user's view they will leave current page if requests are too long to be processed (consider review all queries & back-end codes to improve performance & system resources).